# With Azure can I use it to access document on sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, azure

With Azure can I use it to access document on sharepoint?
How can I setup azure to have credentials to access my company share point?

Thank you.

Comment: can you elaborate your question? from which azure resource are you trying to access your sharepoint ? how are you doing it ?

Comment: SharePoint has the capability to store document libraries in azure blob storage, or expose its own document libraries via an API. This (in theory), should give you two options to investigate for a solution to your question.

Comment: If you're trying to interface with your private corporate network, you may need to look into ExpressRoute (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/expressroute/)